# Android: Livedata Observer gets never called, recylerview list is never submitted, navgraphviewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I have a **ShopFilterFragmentProductFilter** which is inside a **ShopFilterFragmentHolder** which itself holds a **ViewPager2**. This **ShopFilterFragmentHolder** is a DialogFragment which is opened inside my ShopFragment. So ShopFragment -> ShopFilterFragmentHolder (Dialog, ViewPager2) -> ShopFilterFragmentProductFilter. ALL of these Fragments should share the same navgraphscoped viewmodel.

The problem I have is, that when I attach an observer inside my **ShopFilterFragmentProductFilter** to get my recyclerview list from cloud-firestore, this observer never gets called and therefore I get the error message "No Adapter attached, skipping layout". I know that this is not a problem with how I instantiate and assign the adapter to my recyclerview, because when I set a static list (e.g creating a list inside my ShopFilterFragmentProductFilter) everything works.

Why do I don't get the livedata value? To my mind, there is a problem with the viewmodel creation.

Here is my current approach:

### ShopFilterFragmentProductFilter

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ShopFilterFragmentProductFilter : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentShopFilterItemBinding? = null
    private val binding: FragmentShopFilterItemBinding get() = _binding!!
    private val shopViewModel: ShopViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.nav_shop) { defaultViewModelProviderFactory }
    @Inject lateinit var shopFilterItemAdapter: ShopFilterItemAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentShopFilterItemBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        bindObjects()
        submitAdapterList()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        binding.rvShopFilter.adapter = null
        _binding = null
    }

    private fun bindObjects() {
        with(binding) {
            adapter = shopFilterItemAdapter
        }
    }

    private fun submitAdapterList() {
        shopViewModel.shopProductFilterList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            shopFilterItemAdapter.submitList(it)
            shopFilterItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
           toast("SUBMITTED LIST") // this does never get called
        }

        /* // this works
        shopFilterItemAdapter.submitList(
            listOf(
                ShopFilterItem(0, "ITEM 1"),
                ShopFilterItem(0, "ITEM 2"),
                ShopFilterItem(0, "ITEM 3"),
                ShopFilterItem(0, "ITEM 4"),
                ShopFilterItem(0, "ITEM 5"),
            )
        )
         */
    }
}
```

### ViewModel

```
class ShopViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val shopRepository: ShopRepository,
    private val shopFilterRepository: ShopFilterRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private val query = MutableLiveData(QueryHolder("", ""))

    val shopPagingData = query.switchMap { query -> shopRepository.search(query).cachedIn(viewModelScope) }

    val shopProductFilterList: LiveData<List<ShopFilterItem>> = liveData { shopFilterRepository.getProductFilterList() }

    val shopListFilterList: LiveData<List<ShopFilterItem>> = liveData { shopFilterRepository.getListFilterList() }

    fun search(newQuery: QueryHolder) {
        this.query.value = newQuery
    }
}
```

### ShopFilterRepositoryImpl

```
class ShopFilterRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(private val db: FirebaseFirestore) : ShopFilterRepository {

    override suspend fun getProductFilterList(): List<ShopFilterItem> = db.collection(FIREBASE_SERVICE_INFO_BASE_PATH)
        .document(FIREBASE_SHOP_FILTER_BASE_PATH)
        .get()
        .await()
        .toObject<ShopFilterItemHolder>()!!
        .productFilter

    override suspend fun getListFilterList(): List<ShopFilterItem> = db.collection(FIREBASE_SERVICE_INFO_BASE_PATH)
        .document(FIREBASE_SHOP_FILTER_BASE_PATH)
        .get()
        .await()
        .toObject<ShopFilterItemHolder>()!!
        .listFilter
}
```

### Nav_graph

[image]

Comment: Did you check that firestore returns value or not?

Comment: @iamanbansal Yes I did. Firestore returns the correct value. I tested it using `lifecycleScope.launch { val list = shopViewModel.shopFilterRepository.getProductFilterList() Timber.d("LIST IS $list") }`

Comment: Can you try by making 2 same livedata and observe one in one fragment and another in another fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should define it as MutableLiveData:

```
private val shopProductFilterList: MutableLiveData<List<ShopFilterItem>> = MutableLiveData()
```

And in a method in **your viewModel** that gets the data through repository, you should post the LiveData value:

```
fun getProductFilterList() = viewModelScope.launch {
    val dataFetched = repository. getProductFilterList()
    shopProductFilterList.postValue(dataFetched)
}
```